# Why doesn't Openzeppelin's IERC20 has a `decimal()` function?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin

In my projects, getting the `decimals()` is an important task, so I have to sometimes manually add the function in IERC20's interface. But why isn't this function officially in the contract? What am I missing?

Comment: Coz decimals are not a part of the official interface of ERC20.
It is an additional feature for better calculations. No doubt it must be there in an ERC20 contract, but the official interface doesn't define it.